# PHP-gd text display in Japanese is weird

Tags: php, unicode, gd

Finally I had to recompile PHP with `--enable-gd-jis-conv`.
However the text display is wrong, in Japanese.

```
$text = '夏の天気';
$fontfile = '/usr/share/fonts/japanese/TrueType/sazanami-mincho.ttf';

return imagettftext ($image, $size,  $angle,  $x,  $y,  $color, $fontfile, $text);
```

But different *kanji* (Japanese characters) are displayed instead (very different, looks like Chinese).

Could it be an encoding issue?

Using PHP 5.3.3 on RHEL 5.4.

Comment: What is your input encoding and what is your server input configuration? Since Japanese can use several types of encoding (EUC, JIS, SJIS, UTF8)

Comment: Using UTF-8, `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`. The input is made from Emacs utf8 coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run this to get it to work

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding('夏の天気', "SJIS", 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, japanese as a multibyte encoded language has quite a few quirks.
First of all, be sure that your server has the mbstring module installed.

Second, to reduce the chances of possible breakage midway, try to keep all encodings in your site/project consistent: site views and source files should ideally be written with the same encoding.

Specifically for your problem, you might want to try using the following functions:

`mb_http_input` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-input.php

This one will make sure your HTTP input is correctly encoded (ie. form data).

`mb_ internal_ encoding` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Sets the internal encoding used by PHP.

`mb_regex_encoding` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php

Sets the encoding used by PHP for regexes.

`mb_convert_encoding` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

For String conversion.

`mb_convert_variables` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-variables.php

Converts encodings of a whole batch of strings/arrays.

**Edit**: besides, from the name of the module, you might want to try feeding JIS encoded data to the function.

Comment: In order to focus on *gd* tests and avoid some other side-effects, the text is currently entered directly in the php code (夏の天気). The `mb_internal_coding('utf-8')` is set at the beginning. There must be something simple missing - maybe the font is wrong? (on a RHEL English system, `yum install fonts-japanese`).

Answer (score 0):

```
imagettftext($this->im, 58, 0, 50, 100, $text_color, $font, mb_convert_encoding('佳人', 'UTF8', 'UTF-8'));
```

This worked for me. Seems to work accross a few different Japanese fonts.

Comment: @NR please check the answer - isn't it the same?