# PHP echo Japanese on window

Tags: php

I try to echo some Japanese characters: 日本語.

But the result i receive is something like this æ¥æ¬èª.

I tried it on my virtual machine with CentOS, PHP 5.6 and it work. But when i try on Windows 7, PHP 7, result like above.

I guess it must be some config but i don't know where.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo "日本語\n";
?>
```

I even tried:

```
mb_check_encoding('日本語', "SHIFT-JIS");
```

and

```
mb_convert_encoding("日本語", 'UTF-8', array('EUC-JP', 'SHIFT-JIS', 'AUTO','SJIS'));
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: is your php file itself saved in UTF-8 format?

Comment: @Al.UrBasebelonTomeh yes, it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697626/php-gd-text-display-in-japanese-is-weird

Comment: as per examples in @Erubiel's link, perhaps try using SJIS instead of SHIFT-JIS

Comment: I'm sorry. actually in some case i try, it echo right result, it just show like some square symbols in window's command window because command window doesn't understand those symbols, i copy those symbols and paste to notepad and it show right result.